# How do I find out which udev hwdb match is messing with my keys?

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, udev

I bought a Logitech Unifying keyboard K270 and am running Ubuntu 14.04 (yes yes, I'm working on updating it). Everything works except the 'a' and 'b' keys which are reversed for some reason.

I finally found out that it's udev that's messing around with it, but I can't undo it.

```
> udevadm info /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if02-event-kbd
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0015/input/input34/event18
N: input/event18
S: input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if02-event-kbd
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.2-event-kbd
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if02-event-kbd /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.2-event-kbd
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event18
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2/3-2:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0015/input/input34/event18
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_MODEL=USB_Receiver
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=USB\x20Receiver
E: ID_MODEL_ID=c52b
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:2:1.2
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_14_0-usb-0_2_1_2
E: ID_REVISION=1203
E: ID_SERIAL=Logitech_USB_Receiver
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030102:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=02
E: ID_VENDOR=Logitech
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Logitech
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=046d
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_70004=b  <--------
E: KEYBOARD_KEY_70005=a  <--------
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=82
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=397136693
```

I tried overriding it

```
> cat /lib/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboad.hwdb
# XXXX is the 4-digit hex uppercase vendor, and YYYY the 4-digit hex uppercase product.
# keyboard:usb:vXXXXpYYYY*
keyboard:usb:v046D*
  # Logitech keyboard is overriding the A and B keys for some reason
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70004=a
  KEYBOARD_KEY_70005=b
```

To no avail.

How do I write a proper match to override it? I can't find any documentation on how to write a proper match, nor can I find out which rule is inserting that "KEYBOARD_KEY" alias :\

Answer (score 1):

Duuuuuhhh! I had a bluetooth keyboard and had messed with udev before, trying to make that one work, but gave up and left behind configuration.

```
> grep  KEYBOARD_KEY_70004 /etc/udev/hwdb.d/* /lib/udev/hwdb.d/*
/etc/udev/hwdb.d/90-bluetooth-keyboard.hwdb:  KEYBOARD_KEY_70004=b
```

From the doc

> udevadm hwdb [options]
>         Maintain the hardware database index in /lib/udev/hwdb.bin.
>
> ```
>   --update
>       Compile the hardware database information located in **/lib/udev/hwdb.d/**, **/etc/udev/hwdb.d/** and store it in /lib/udev/hwdb.bin. This should be done after any update to the source files; it will not be called automatically.
>       The running udev daemon will detect a new database on its own and does not need to be notified about it.
> ```

However, if somebody has documentation on how to write a proper match, please point me to it.

Cheers